A naive looking question about Gelfand-Kirillov dimension
Let $A$ and $B$ two affine algebras, $A$ a subalgebra of $B$. If we have a left $A$-module $M$ we can extend the scalars: $B \otimes_A M$. I will denote the resulting $B$-module by $N$
How are $\operatorname{GK}(M)$ as an $A$-module and $\operatorname{GK}(N)$ as a $B$-module related?
When I thought about this, I went to Krause and Lenagan's book, and after that to McConnell and Robson's book, and I couldn't find anything.
In my specific case of interest, $A$ is a rank $n$ Weyl algebra, and $B$ a localization of it by a single polynomial.
Does anybody has any references about this?

This is not what "extension of scalars" means. If $M$ is an $A$-module, then the extension of scalars is the $B$-module $B\otimes_A M$ (while $M$ has no natural $B$-module structure a priori). If $N$ is a $B$-module, then indeed $N$ is an $A$-module by restriction of scalars.

From memory you can find information related to your specific case of interest in this book: https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/north-holland-mathematical-library/vol/21/suppl/C
